# Error when loading Twitter search results

Tags: python, json, twitter

This may be a dumb question but I cannot figure it out for the life of me
Please excuse my confusing variable naming. I would be ecstatic if anyone could tell me why the following error is happening and/or any other mistakes any my code.

> JSON: error expecting property name line 1 column 2 (char 1)

```
import json
import twitter
a = twitter.get_account("@Suppert2")
q = "cxdffcfctftcvft"
ac = twitter.search(a,q, count=1, parameters=None)
abg = str(ac)
print (abg)
ah = json.loads(abg)  # here is where the error is occurring 
print ah["completed_in"]
```

And when you print `abg` it comes out as:

```
{u'search_metadata': {u'count': 1, u'completed_in': 0.048, u'max_id_str': u'718234026394443782', u'since_id_str': u'0', u'refresh_url': u'?since_id=718234026394443782&q=x597567654dfv&include_entities=1', u'since_id': 0, u'query': u'x597567654dfv', u'max_id': 718234026394443782L}, u'statuses': []}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to load JSON here, `twitter.search()` returns you a Python dictionary in the first place, just use it:

```
ac = twitter.search(a,q, count=1, parameters=None)
print(ac["statuses"])
print(ac["search_metadata"]["completed_in"])
```

Comment: There's not just "no need" to load JSON here; you _cannot_ load JSON here. Because it's not JSON.

Comment: :0 oh my goodness I'm an idiot I over thought that way to much thank you so much man

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid JSON, you can use http://jsonlint.com to verify it.

Comment: Yes, this is valid: ```{
 "search_metadata": {
  "count": 1,
  "completed_in": 0.048
 }
}```

Comment: Why were my comments removed??

Answer (score 0):

**It looks kind of like JSON, but it isn't JSON.**

Those `u` prefixes, the `L` suffix and the use of single-quotes all make it invalid JSON. That's why treating it as JSON fails (and you can see that it's not JSON by attempting to validate it at http://jsonlint.com, always a good first debugging step).

This string is actually the string representation of a Python dictionary, which you got from `str(ac)` because **the Twitter API gave you a Python dictionary** (in `ac`).

So use `ac` directly, e.g.

```
print(ac["search_metadata"]["completed_in"])
```